# Checkbox doesn't work with Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have multiple inputs in my form but only `input="text"` works: the checkbox and radio are not working (hidden input doesn't work either)

I'm using

```
<form id="form">
 <div>
 <input type="text" name="val_1">
 <input type="text" name="val_2">
 </div>

 <div>
 <input type="checkbox" name="val_3" value="1"> 
 <input type="radio" name="val_4" value="1">
 </div>
</form>
```

and in JS:

```
type: "POST", 
url: 'page.php', 
data: $("#form").serialize(),
async: false,
```

With `echo print_r($_POST)`, I have just

```
Array
(
    [val_1] => test
    [val_2] => test
)
```

Why are `val_3` and `val_4` not working?

Comment: did you check the checkbox?

Comment: Yes... i have test with checked="checked" too and not result

Comment: are you wrapping your stuff in ajax call ? look at the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/EMWU/wb45v/14/  IF you check the checkbox and radio and look at the post variables in your webmaster tools, you can see both val_3 and val_4 included.

Comment: Sorry guys its me... jquery dont accept id like id="var0", with id="var_0" its work...

Comment: How you doing form submission?